# Heroku add new files into my facebook appgit

Tags: heroku, cloud, addition, fbjs

I am trying to add some files to my space into heroku to working my facebook app...

I first create a index.ejs and all is good

then I create a 2 new files: test.html and credits.php

I try to send them to heroku with command:

git commit -am "newfiles" but there is some error

also i tri with git add myappfolder/view/test.html but no working

How I can add this two files to my facebook space app

(I select node.js as language for creating fb app... can 
 then upload php and .html files)

Answer (score 5):

simply write

```
git add ./ 
git commit -am "newfiles" 
git push heroku
```

so that all the files could push into server